# How to define the location of ViewComponent views during startup in a .net Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, startup

I want to move the views out of the components folder under Pages into their own folder. Does this have to be defined in the startup? How is it defined?

For example:

The views are currently under: /Pages/Share/Components

I want to put them under: /Components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For configuring the custom search location, you could try code below:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

And then the project structure for Components like

- Project

  - Components

    - View Component Name

      - View Name

Comment: How can we get rid of the `Component` and the `ViewComponent` part of that `{0}` string? I effectively want `{0}` to be JUST the view name so if I did `o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}.cshtml")` and called `return View("MyFolder/MyViewName")` it'd look in `Project>MyFolder>MyViewName.cshtml`